# Нужна помощь с jquery tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ребят, помогите пожалуйста.
Есть 3 кнопки, по клику на каждую открывается одно и тоже модальное окно. 
Внутри окна есть табы(3 вкладки).

https://codepen.io/brezze/pen/YjBgbw

Нужно чтобы например по клику на Button 3, модально окно открывалось с активным третим табом (Содержимое 3).
По клику на button 2, в модальном окне должно быть активно Содержимое 2 и так далее. спасибо

```
<ul class="nav">
  <li><a href="#modal">Button 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#modal">Button 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#modal">Button 3</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="modal mfp-hide" id="modal">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="tabs">
        <span class="tab">Вкладка 1</span>
        <span class="tab">Вкладка 2</span>
        <span class="tab">Вкладка 3</span>        
    </div>
    <div class="tab_content">
        <div class="tab_item">Содержимое 1</div>
        <div class="tab_item">Содержимое 2</div>
        <div class="tab_item">Содержимое 3</div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

$(".tab_item").not(":first").hide();
$(".wrapper .tab").click(function() {
    $(".wrapper .tab").removeClass("active").eq($(this).index()).addClass("active");
    $(".tab_item").hide().eq($(this).index()).fadeIn()
}).eq(0).addClass("active");

$('.nav a').magnificPopup({
  type:'inline'
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот как-то так

```js
$('.tab_item').not(':first').hide();
$('.wrapper .tab').click(function() {
 $('.wrapper .tab')
    .removeClass('active')
    .eq($(this).index())
    .addClass('active');
 $('.tab_item')
    .hide()
    .eq($(this).index())
    .fadeIn();
}).eq(0).addClass('active');


$('.nav li').click(function(){
  $('.tab_item')
    .hide()
    .eq($(this).index())
    .fadeIn();
});
```

```css
body, ul, li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 40px;
}

.nav a {
 text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
}

.nav li {
  margin: 0 25px;
  padding: 15px 30px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 700;
  background-color: #5CB85C;
}

.modal {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 30px;
  position: relative;
}

.tabs {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.tab {
  background-color: blue;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 0 15px;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: arial;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="nav">
  <li><a href="#modal">Button 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#modal">Button 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#modal">Button 3</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="modal mfp-hide" id="modal">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="tabs">
        <span class="tab">Вкладка 1</span>
        <span class="tab">Вкладка 2</span>
        <span class="tab">Вкладка 3</span>        
    </div>
    <div class="tab_content">
        <div class="tab_item">Содержимое 1</div>
        <div class="tab_item">Содержимое 2</div>
        <div class="tab_item">Содержимое 3</div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```